# Line breaks in table cell

Tags: php, html, nl2br

I don't understand why nl2br doesn't work in my table cell :

```
<table><tr><td>
<?php echo nl2br($sText); ?>
</td></tr></table>
```

There are 2 paragraphs in $sText but it displays 2 
 instead of the first paragraph

When I don't use table, the break line appears...

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of $sText.

Answer (score 0):

it displays 2 br instead of the first paragraph

Comment: what does paragraph mean? This function inserts HTML linebreaks before newlines like `"this\nis\na\ntest" => "this<br>\nis<br>\na<br>\ntest"`, so post the contents of `$sText`...

Answer (score 0):

here's the text :

> There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but
> the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected
> humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.
> If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure
> there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.
>
> All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat
> predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator
> on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words,
> combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate
> Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is
> therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or
> non-characteristic words etc.

I want a newline.